# Do I get my question back from CW status when I rollback?

Tags: feature-request, community-wiki

I tried to show what I have already done and so I kept on editing my own [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/106144/19341). I turned CW after 13 edits or so. Since it's a quite special question, I don't think it should belong there, but I accept the rules and so be it.

But, do I get my question back when I do a rollback to revision 9 or to 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. But in this case you can flag for moderator attention. I've cleared the CW status on the post.

See also [this Meta question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1518/1543) and [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/1797/1543).

Comment: Thanks, do I have 10 more revisions before it get's CW again or will it happen with the next one?

Comment: @draks: Moderator action nullifies the 10 edits $\implies$ CW rule - the post will only become CW again if a moderator does it manually.